# Unable to connect remote server mysql database from C# application

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to connect my C# application to web server database(mysql). I am using the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace mySqlConnectivity
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string myConStr;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myConStr = "SERVER=xxx.xx.xxx.xx;Port=80;DATABASE=EmSystem;UID=xxx;PASSWORD=xxx;compress=true";
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int mobNo;
            string mobile = textBox3.Text;
            int.TryParse(mobile, out mobNo);

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConStr);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO phonebook(Id,uname,MobileNo) VALUES(@id,@uname,@MobileNo)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", mobNo);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Close();

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This code is working for local server database But when I am trying to connect with web server database it is giving the following error.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at mySqlConnectivity.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\VS\mySqlConnectivity\mySqlConnectivity\Form1.cs:line 35
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

My IP address and Port is correct because using this I am able to access mysql server database.

Can any body please tell me where is the problem and it there any other way to connect C# application with web server database.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you install `MYSQL Connector` to connect the MYSQL DB.

Comment: yes I have installed mysql-connector-net-6.7.4

Comment: @AmitAgrawal, you don't need to install it.  The library works fine if you reference it from the project.  geeta, did you open the port in the firewalls on client/server?

Comment: Your code shows port 80, which will be reserved for serving html requests.

Comment: are you sure your webserver allow remote connection to your db on their host ?

Comment: @ps2goat I have used 80 because when i am logging to phpmyadmin database using Ip address it is showing port number 80.

Comment: @ps2goat will you please tell me how to  open the port in the firewalls on client/server?

Comment: Is it a windows server? give us specs...  What firewall/internet security suite do you have installed?

Comment: @ps2goat yes it is windows server.Actually we have bought space from net4.in where mySql is installed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see (SERVER=xxx.xx.xxx.xx;Port=80;) you are trying to connect to port 80 (defalut http port). The defalut MySQL port is 3306, so you should change the port to correct one.

Comment: I have used 3306 but the error was coming Error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the port 3306, right now you are using 80, which is port where the web server is listening not mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

In .ini file set following values:

```
net_read_timeout=99999 

net_write_timeout=99999
```

Then restarting  db server

This will work.

Comment: how to access the .ini file on remote server ?